# How to make sure NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey ist set in Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can i make sure NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey is set correctly for all files/folders using the simulator (i've currently no real device available)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that using:

```
NSError *error;
id enabledFlag = nil;
[yourFileURL getResourceValue: &enabledFlag forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
NSLog (@"NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey enabled %@", enabledFlag)
```

But there is no way to check that using the iCloud option present in the simulator.